# Sqlcipher, Windows: encryption succeeds but produces strange results

Tags: sqlcipher

I used `sqlcipher_export()`, exactly as specified [here](http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-api/#sqlcipher_export), to encrypt an existing Sqlite database. It all went fine - no errors, the resulting database is created and has a reasonable size. However, I am not able to open the encrypted database, even though I specify the correct key using `PRAGMA key`. Unencrypted databases open without problems.

Moreover, the encrypted database looks strange; the header seems to be encrypted, but not the data. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaBpS.png, it's an image showing binary comparison between encrypted (left) and unencrypted (right) databases.

In the debugger I can see that, during the encryption, the program goes through `sqlcipher_page_cipher()`, but most of the time (every time except for 2 invocations) the following clause is executed, and the function returns early:

```
  /* just copy raw data from in to out when key size is 0
   * i.e. during a rekey of a plaintext database */ 
  if(c_ctx->key_sz == 0) {
    memcpy(out, in, size);
    return SQLITE_OK;
  }
```

SQL issued during encryption:

```
ATTACH DATABASE 'encrypted.db' AS encrypted KEY '12345'; 
SELECT sqlcipher_export('encrypted'); 
DETACH DATABASE encrypted;
```

SQL issued during opening:

```
// open database
PRAGMA key = '12345'; 
// try to read database - "file is encrypted or not a database"
```

CODEC_TRACE logs generated during encryption and decryption are [here](http://yp.lviv.ua/tmp/sqlcipher_log.zip).

(In case it is important how I compiled Sqlcipher: I created an Sqlcipher amalgamation on a Linux machine, copied the resulting C file to a Windows machine, compiled it in Visual C++ Express, and linked to a precompiled OpenSSL DLL.)

Comment: the codec trace shows it processing ~17000 pages. does encrypted.db exist before you start the export?

Comment: No, it doesn't exist. (Thanks for the fast response!)

Comment: I just ran through a test with a 138 MB database, exactly as documented on the sqlcipher site on windows. it worked without issues, the resulting database was encrypted. I'm wondering if there is some issue with your build. Can you try using the command line and see if it works?

Comment: I corrected the paragraph starting with "In the debugger I can see", please take a look. I use the library as a DLL, so it's not immediately possible to use the command line interpreter, but I can switch over to Linux and compile the interpreter.

Comment: More findings... At the start of encryption, `c_ctx->key_sz` is initialized to a positive number in `sqlcipher_codec_ctx_set_cipher`, but then the memory location suddenly changes to zero in here:

`CODEC2(pPager, pData, pPg->pgno, 7, return SQLITE_NOMEM, pData2);` ( function `pager_write()` ). 

The stack trace points inside libeay32.dll (the precompiled OpenSSL DLL). OpenSSL seems to corrupt the memory belonging to `c_ctx`, perhaps due to `pData` being pretty close in memory. Smells like some binary incompatibility...

Comment: Yes, that would definitely cause a problem. Can you try to build your own OpenSSL? Or, you could buy the binaries: http://sqlcipher.net/downloads/

Comment: Eventually I found that the `HMAC_Init_ex` call in `sqlcipher_page_hmac` corrupts memory. In [this image](http://i.snag.gy/rbMCl.jpg) memory belonging to ctx->hctx is enclosed in a red polygon. Bytes in red font signify the memory changed by `HMAC_Init_ex`. So bytes in red font outside the red polygon are corrupted memory. The byte in a blue rectangle belongs to ctx->key_sz - it suddenly becomes zero. This is why the data is copied, and not encrypted, in subsequent calls of `sqlcipher_page_cipher()`. OpenSSL bug? Tomorrow I will try to update OpenSSL and see what happens.

Comment: Upgrading OpenSSL solved the problem. The debugger shows that only the HMAC context's memory is now initialized. 

Well it is rather unsettling that OpenSSL can corrupt memory....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Root cause: Calls to OpenSSL's `HMAC_Init_ex()` in `sqlcipher_page_hmac()` corrupted memory that belonged to `c_ctx->key_sz`, setting it to zero. `c_ctx->key_sz` was adjacent to a parameter passed to `HMAC_Init_ex()`. (Details can be found in one of the comments to the original post.) This caused `sqlcipher_page_cipher()` to write plaintext pages to the encrypted file, instead of encrypted pages. Which didn't make sense and made the resulting database unusable.

Upgrading OpenSSL from 0.9.8k to 1.0.0i fixed the problem.